# Discord.py: Editing a message sent by bot according to how many reactions that message got

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I'm making a bot that prints certain data from a file (using pandas) into an embedded message.
That embedded message is a list of data, and I've been trying to update it by using emotes.

For some reason, none of the Stack Overflow answers worked. I've tried multiple fixes like below and they would raise my errors etc. which I wasn't able to fix.

> name = await client.send(channel, embed=embed)

> name.add_reaction("emote name")

Discord.py version: 1.3.4

Response from bot:

[image]

Desired response(s) from bot:
[image]

code snippet:

```
                    embed.add_field(name="__**{}**__".format(trend_name2), value="__Level__: **{0}**\n__Category__: **{1}**\n__Position__: **{2}**\n\n**{3}** Trends until **{4}** "
                                                                             "trend\n(**{5} days and {6} hours**)\n\n ‎".format(
                    trend_level2, trend_category2.title(), trend_position2, min(lookup_difference), trend_name2.title(), days_until_trend, hours_until_trend))
                print(lookup_index)
                z += 1
                if z == 6:
                    embed_fields.append(embed)
                    z = 0
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Level list", color=0x00d9ff)
            page_ = 0
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed_fields[page_])

            # On right arrow reaction clicked:
            #   page += 1
            # On left arrow reaction clicked:
            #   page -= 1
            # Edit message to embed=embed_fields[page_]
            #
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not your own code, disputils is a really nice library for simple emoji menus like yours: [disputils](https://github.com/LiBa001/disputils). It's a simple way to make menus, confirmations, and more.

Comment: Looks very nice indeed, but it doesn't seem to work. Although it prints the first embed, it doesn't add the emotes. And when I myself add the emotes it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Are you sure you are using it right? I've been using that library for quite a while and it works perfectly. Showing some code would be nice, since you shouldn't have to add emojis (it automatically adds arrows) and you can pass in custom ones if necessary.

Comment: Hey there, it works now. I believe I didn't enter the ctx var or the embed list had only 1 entry. But thanks anyways

Comment: Good to hear that worked out, and thanks for accepting the answer.